# Can you help me with my recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have this simple function that I am calculating correctly, but my output statements are off. I have tried other places were the cout statement is commented, but not working.

```
int recursiveFunc(int n) {
    int val;    // value at nth sequence


    //cout << "(" << n << ") = " << val << endl;

    if (n == 1 ) {      // base case 1
        val = -1;
        // outputs before function call
    }
    else if (n == 2) {  // base case 2
        val = -1;
        // outputs before function call
    }
    else {      // recursive case
        //cout << "(" << n << ") = << val << endl;
        val = 2*(recursiveFunc(n-1) + recursiveFunc(n-2));
        cout << "(" << n << ") = " << val << endl;   // not sure where to put cout statement

    }

    return val;
}
```

I am looking for an output like (for example n = 5):

```
(1) = -1
(2) = -1
(3) = -4
(4) = -10
(5) = -28
```

currently, my output looks like:

```
(1) = -1
(2) = -1
(3) = -4
(4) = -10
(3) = -4    // here an nth term is displayed twice
(5) = -28
```

Comment: Your posted code has a syntax error on the `cout` line, I think you're missing a double-quote.

Comment: @Dai Thanks, that was a typo on posting it here

Comment: Also, it's spelled `recursive` ;)

Comment: The reason why you see 2 outputs for `(3)` is because you are calling `recursiveFunc(3)` twice.  With `n=5`, `recursiveFunc(n-1)` is `recursiveFunc(4)` which calls `recursiveFunc(3)`, and `recursiveFunc(n-2)` is `recursiveFunc(3)`

Comment: Your current code doesn't render and output when `n < 3` btw, so the first output will always be `(3) = -4`.

Comment: Do you want to print what the function is actually being called with, to trace execution? Then it will repeat, because the calls repeat. What is your goal?

Comment: Why do you keep showing output at `(1)` and `(2)` when the posted code clearly does not output anything for those cases? Is the `cout` really inside the `else` block as shown?

Comment: @TomZych I put the output statements for the base cases before the function call in main

Comment: @Manny Please post enough code to replicate your results. Either remove the output from statements not shown, or show those statements. (c.f. [mre]).

Comment: @Manny You removed the more illustrative examples (not what was requested). Your output still does not match the code. When called using `recursiveFunc(5)`, the code as presented produces only 4 lines of output, not 6. Please provide a [mre] by showing "the output statements for the base cases before the function call in main".

Comment: @JaMiT I only need to post what is necessary (to avoid bloat), please read the inline comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `cout` statement to outside the function and it works fine.

```
int recursiveFunc(int n) {
    int val;    // value at nth sequence

    if (n == 1) {      // base case 1
        val = -1;
    }
    else if (n == 2) {  // base case 2
        val = -1;
    }
    else {      // recursive case
        val = 2 * (recursiveFunc(n - 1) + recursiveFunc(n - 2));
    }

    return val;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        std::cout << "(" << i << ") = " << recursiveFunc(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(1) = -1
(2) = -1
(3) = -4
(4) = -10
(5) = -28
(6) = -76
(7) = -208
(8) = -568
(9) = -1552
```

Answer (score 0):

Right off the top-of-my-head, a possible fix is to keep track of the highest `n` output so-far already and only output when a larger `n` is encountered. (This is probably not the *best* solution, but I'm feeling too tired and lazy to think about alternatives)

Don't use a global variable for this ([mutable global state is an anti-pattern!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)) - you'll need to pass it as another parameter.

```
int output_n_and_val( int n, int val, int& biggestN ) {

    if( n > biggestN ) {
        cout << "(" << n << ") = " << val << endl;
        biggestN = n;
    }
    return val;
}

int recursiveFuncImpl( int n, int& biggestN ) {

    if( n == 1 ) {
        return output_n_and_val( n, -1, biggestN );
    }
    else if( n == 2 ) {
        return output_n_and_val( n, -1, biggestN );
    }
    else {
        int val =  2 * ( recursiveFuncImpl( n - 1, biggestN ) + recursiveFuncImpl( n - 2, biggestN ) );
        return output_n_and_val( n, val, biggestN );
    }
}

// Entrypoint function:
int recursiveFunc( int n ) {

    int biggestN = -1;
    return recursiveFuncImpl( n, biggestN );
}

int main()
{
    recursiveFunc( 10 );

    recursiveFunc( 5 );

    return 0;
}
```

The downside to this approach is that because of the `n == 2` case-handling is encountered before `n == 1` you'll never get the output `(1) = -1`. Fixing that is an exercise left for the reader.

Comment: Remember that C++ does not make any guarantees about order of evaluation. It might call the function with `n-1` before `n-2`, or vice-versa. The only way to be sure is to call them separately, to create a sequence point.

Comment: @TomZych Indeed! Though I didn't want to deviate too far from the OP's code so they could see how my code is derived from theirs. I'm hoping their compiler gives them a warning about unspecified-evaluation-order from their use of a call-site as an operand.

Answer (score 0):

you should use an array to store values that you have computed, for example

```
const int N = 1000000;
int values[N]; // remember to memset to 0 first

int recursiveFunc(int n) {
    if(n < 0) return 0;
    if(values[n] != 0) return values[n];

    int val;    // value at nth sequence

    if (n == 1) {      // base case 1
        val = -1;
    }
    else if (n == 2) {  // base case 2
        val = -1;
    }
    else {      // recursive case
        val = 2 * (recursiveFunc(n - 1) + recursiveFunc(n - 2));
    }

    return values[n] = val;
}

int main() {
    memset(values, 0, sizeof(values));
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        std::cout << "(" << i << ") = " << recursiveFunc(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```